# How to set settings for a subproject in sbt shell (without using project command)?

Tags: scala, sbt

In sbt shell how do I set a setting for a subproject?

I know I can `project subproject` then `set key := value`, but I don't want to have to keep switching projects. Ideally something not too different from:

```
set key in subproject := value
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have defined your projects in `build.sbt`, and they seem not to be visible in the sbt console. At least in the current version of sbt - see [this issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1059) and [this issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/1456) that were in fact fixed just a couple of days ago (!)

I have found two ways to overcome this limitation.

### Use quotes around the project id

```
set version in "projectId" := "some-version"
```

### Create a full build definition in project/Build.scala file

With the following build definition file `build/Build.scala`:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object Build extends Build {
  lazy val projectA, projectB = project
}
```

you should be fine to execute `set version in projectA := "1.42-SNAPSHOT` with the expected effect.

Additionally you could just have the `build/Build.scala` containing the project definition and rest of the configuration have in `build.sbt` for each submodule. It'd work perfectly fine with `set`.

Comment: Only thing is it's the project's id, not its name. Might be worth changing.

Comment: I didn't know that projects from `build.sbt` are not visible in the shell! Thanks for sharing the news.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski if I understand it correctly and the linked issues are just about this, then it seems that it should be possible in the next sbt release.

Comment: That's correct! And that's why I didn't see it in my custom build of sbt :) See my change. Hope you don't mind my changes.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I have learned to live with them ;). Even those removing `.` from method calls ;). But honestly - valuable changes are always good for the community so thanks! :)

Comment: I might start using `.` again where it improves understanding and helps the Scala type inferencer.