# How can one set a value for all subprojects in sbt shell?

Tags: scala, sbt

Although similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905717/how-to-set-settings-for-a-subproject-in-sbt-shell-without-using-project-command?rq=1), I'd like to set the same value to all subprojects.

```
set key in * := value
```

The above doesn't work, and there's no issue if I do this one by one (but it is tedious).

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why did you think that it will work? Are such "wild cards" mentioned anywhere in sbt documentation ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Used to a "shell" being a *shell*. I didn't expect to it to work, but I was hoping for a stroke of bashism.

Comment: Looks like you need to read about "What is a shell?" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing) . GNOME and Windows GUI are also shell.

Comment: What key you are trying to set? Is it settings like version, org. etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
set every key := value
```

See `help set`.